# Is there a way to overwrite a table with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

I have a CSV file that I am loading into my database. I want the previous data in the table to be overwritten and not appended every time I load my CSV file. Is it possible to do this within a single query?

Is the only solution to `TRUNCATE` the table and then utilize the `LOAD DATA INFILE` queries?

Comment: If a record was there before loading, and that same record is not present in the file, what result do you want: should the old record be retained, or deleted?

Comment: The old record should be deleted.

Comment: In that case, you have to `truncate` first, the `LOAD DATA` command cannot do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a primary key, you can use `REPLACE`.  As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) states:

> The REPLACE and IGNORE modifiers control handling of input rows that
>   duplicate existing rows on unique key values:
>
> - If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows. In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index
>     as an existing row. See Section 13.2.9, “REPLACE Statement”.

However, if you want to replace the existing table, then truncate the table first and then load.